# OrientDB - Linking Records in a Transaction Does not Work

Tags: orientdb

#### Scenario

I have two classes. Schema given below;

```
CLASS B {
    PROPERTY name STRING
}

CLASS A {
    PROPERTY name STRING
    PROPERTY bLinkList LINKLIST B
}
```

I want to insert a record to `Class B`, insert a record to `Class A` and link new record of `Class B` to the new record of `Class A`. I want to do this in a transaction.

#### Code

I'm using a server side function for doing this. Following is the code.

```
db.begin();

var bRid = db.command("INSERT INTO B (name) VALUES(\"Jack\") RETURN @rid");
db.command("INSERT INTO A (name) VALUES(\"Jack\")");
db.command("UPDATE A ADD bLinkList = " + bRid);

db.commit();
```

#### Facts

I'm using OrientDB Version : 2.0.3. My DB is a Document DB

#### Observation

With in a transaction, this does not work. For `bLinkList` in `Class A`, null is inserted
With out the transaction this works.

I've checked the rid returned after insertion with in the transaction and as expected they are temporary rids. As per documentation and few forum posts I've referred, the records are sent to the server and the transaction is re-created in the server side before the commit, hence the consistency of the temporary rids created with in the transaction at client side are maintained.

Unfortunately this does not work. Some help to figure out what's going in here would be highly appreciated.

Cheers!

Omega